# Unable to match character groups with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to match the regex `\[[A-Z\s]*\]`. It seems like grep is unable to interpret `[A-Z\s]` as `any upper-case letter or space`. `\[.*\]` works, but is not specific enough for me.

A quick look into `grep --help` reveals that there are multiple options for regex.

```
  -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
  -F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated strings
  -G, --basic-regexp        PATTERN is a basic regular expression (BRE)
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
  -e, --regexp=PATTERN      use PATTERN for matching
```

I do not seem to get it to work with any of these options. What am I doing wrong?

Background: I would like to go through logging information. The logger sometimes outputs information with `[INFO]` or `[WARN ]` or similar.

Comment: Then use `\[[A-Z ]*\]` or `\[[A-Z[:space:]]*\]`, why use `\s`? Actually, with `-P` option, it should work.

Comment: The logs contain lines like `loger_xyz [ERROR]: Something went wrong here!`. I would like to match all lines that `[WARN]`, `[ERROR ]` or similar things in it. So this`\[` means "match an opening bracket". Then match any upper-case chars or whitespaces `[A-Z\s]*` until you find a closing bracket `\[`

Comment: With `-P` option, it works.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is `\s` not the same like just writing `[:space:]`? Usually `\s` matches spaces

Comment: `\s` works in `grep` with `-P` option,i.e. with PCRE regex engine. It is not usually supported by POSIX BRE/ERE, it is a GNU extension. There is almost never "usually" with regexes as there are a lot of flavors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl compatible regular expressions...

```
grep -P "\[[A-Z\s]*\]"
```

...work for me. Input:

```
[INFO]
[WARN ]
[TEST2]
```

Output:

```
[INFO]
[WARN ]
```

If you don't have PCRE available on your system,

```
grep "\[[A-Z[:space:]]*\]"
```

will work out of grep's builtin basic syntax.

Comment: By `A-Z` the OP probably intends it to mean "upper case letters". For that to work in all locales you should use `[:upper:]` instead of `A-Z` (in some locales, for example, the letters are ordered `aAbBcC...zZ` so `A-Z` means `all upper and lower case letters except "a"`). You don't need to escape the `]` so `grep '\[[[:upper:][:space:]]*]'` would work.

Comment: @EdMorton: The jump from `[A-Z]` to `[:upper:]` is a non-trivial one, and one I wouldn't take for granted. As `[A-Z]` was what the OP asked about, I felt going on a tangent on `[:upper:]` would be unasked-for. As for escaping the `]`, I consider the unnecessary escape at the end to be actually beneficial for readability.